# Copy Whole Spreadsheet and keep Custom Permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, protected

I have a budget spreadsheet for 2023. It has protected ranges. The permissions are set so that myself and my manager can make edits to all of the protected ranges (I did this through setting a custom permission on the protected ranges). I want to copy the entire spreadsheet so that I can make a 2024 budget spreadsheet. When I do this, it saves the protected ranges, but leaves my manager off. Is there a way to duplicate the entire spreadsheet and keep protected ranges if they are a custom permission?

As I mentioned, I tried copying the spreadsheet and it kept the protected ranges, but it removed my manager. I want it to keep both of us as editors to protected ranges. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: - [Protection.addEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#addeditorsemailaddresses)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.